# How to compact two \psclip commands?

Tags: pstricks

```
\documentclass[border=15pt,pstricks,12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[unit=1.5cm](-2,-2)(2,2)
%%%
\psclip{\pscircle(0,0){1.2}}
\psframe[dimen=m,fillstyle=vlines,linestyle=none](-.8,-1.2)(.8,1.2)%%
\endpsclip%%
\psellipse[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=white](0,0)(1,.8)
%%%
\psclip{\pscircle[linestyle=none](0,0){1.2}}
\psframe[dimen=m,linestyle=dashed,dash=.1 .05](-.8,-1.2)(.8,1.2)%%
\endpsclip%%
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Didn't work with `XeLaTeX` which has a problem with the command `eoclip':

```
\documentclass[border=15pt,pstricks,12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[unit=1.5cm](-2,-2)(2,2)
\psclip[clipcommand=eoclip]{
  \pscustom{%        
    \pscircle(0,0){1.2}
    \psellipse(0,0)(1,.8)}%
  }
\psframe[dimen=middle,fillstyle=hlines,linestyle=dashed,dash=0.1 
0.05](-.8,-1.25)(.8,1.25)
\endpsclip
\psline[linestyle=dashed,dash=0.1 0.05](-0.8,-0.55)(-0.8,0.55)
\psline[linestyle=dashed,dash=0.1 0.05](0.8,-0.55)(0.8,0.55)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: :-), Your code is missing. See my code and my picture! :-)

Comment: Could have been done by yourself ...

Comment: :-), I am a curious person so I usually learn new things. And can you see a other question by myself ...

Comment: What is the " dimen=middle "? Why do we need it?

Comment: `dimen=middle` is the default for `psline`, but not for `psframe`